# How to use SHA256 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, qr-code, sha256

I'm current working on a Laravel project about QR code in a residency. Everytime the home owner fills the details about a guest, the system will generate a unique 6-digit code. Now, I only want to hash the unique code in SHA256, but it's not working. May I get some help?

This is my GuestController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Guest;
use App\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;

class GuestController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.guest.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $guest = new Guest;
        $guest->code = random_int(100000, 999999);
        $guest->hash = Hash::make(hash('sha256', $guest['code']));
        $guest->guestname = $request->input('guestname');
        $guest->guestphone = $request->input('guestphone');
        $guest->guestic = $request->input('guestic');
        $guest->guestcar = $request->input('guestcar');
        $guest->datevisit = $request->input('datevisit');
        $guest->timevisit = $request->input('timevisit');
        $guest->save();
        
        return redirect('show-pass')->with('status', 'Guest Added Successfully');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $guest = Guest::find($id);
        $guest->delete();
        return redirect('show-pass')->with('status', 'Guest Deleted Successfully');
    }

    public function generate($id)
    {
        $guest = Guest::findOrFail($id);
        $qrcode = QrCode::size(150)->generate($guest->code);
        return view('pages.guest.generate', compact('qrcode'));
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        //Get the search value from the request
        $search = $request->input('search');

        //Search in the code from the list
        $guest = Guest::query()
                ->where('code', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
                ->get();
        
        //Return the search view with the results compacted
        return view('pages.guest.search', compact('guest'));

    } 

}
```

Comment: why are you hashing that twice?  but what "isn't working"?

Comment: idk why did i hash it twice... i was only following some other codes  it said that the class ```App\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash``` not found. but it's ok now, i've found the solution. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `sha256` hash and then hash that hash with `bcrypt` throught Laravel's `Hash` facade. Laravel's `Hash` facade only supports `bcrypt` and `Argon2`. That explains why you're getting different results.

Just use the vanilla PHP `hash()` function and remove the Laravel `Hash`.

```
$guest->hash = hash('sha256', $guest['code']);
```

Comment: oh, i see. thank you so much, your answer helped!!